# Event binded to dynamically generated HTML get called automatically

Tags: jquery, angularjs, file-upload, angularjs-scope

I am trying to bind event to dynamically generated html in AngularJs controller, but I can't. I found following code snippet

```
var div = angular.element("del-" + input.name);
div.bind('onclick', $scope.DeleteImage());
```

But it immediately calls the `DeleteImage()` function. I want to add deleteImage icon with functionality, to remove image from ImageuploadList. Any Idea, how to do that?
Here is my code:

```js
 function readImageURL(input) {
            if (input) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#pageImageList').append('<span class="upload-image recent-images"> <a id="del-' + input.name + '" href="javascript:void(0);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ></a><img src="' + e.target.result + '" id="' + input.name + '" width="100%" height="100%"></span>')
                    var div = angular.element("del-" + input.name);
                    div.bind('onclick', $scope.DeleteImage());

                    $scope.imageUpload.push({
                        ImageUrl: e.target.result,
                        ImageName: input.name
                    });
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at code "div.bind('onclick', $scope.DeleteImage());", its actually calling the function.

Please check if you want to add "$scope.DeleteImage()" in single quotes

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
div.bind('onclick', $scope.DeleteImage());
```

will bind onclick to the *result* of calling DeleteImage.  You need to passing in a function pointer, not call the function (which () does), ie:

```
div.bind('onclick', $scope.DeleteImage);
```

or use an inline function:

```
div.bind('onclick', function() { $scope.DeleteImage(); });
```

Comment: it works well, but need little modification, like below:
div.bind('click', function() { $scope.DeleteImage(); });

instead of 'onclick' put just 'click'.

Comment: Not knowing what's available in (your?) angularjs controller, I kept with the event name that you were binding to.  Glad you got it sorted.